# GNU Parallel - command not found

Tags: linux, bash, gnu, gnu-parallel

I'm trying to use [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) together with [SLURM](https://slurm.schedmd.com/documentation.html) to run several instances of the same script with different input parameters. For that, I allocate 3 nodes via SLURM and then I create several threads via GNU Parallel and these threads are running the Python scripts, each one of them utilizing just one CPU core.

Also, the scripts are quite memory-heavy, so that I need to be able to restart the job, if it fails because of insufficient RAM. For that, I resorted to use `--retry-failed` and `--retries` flags.

My problem is, that all jobs except the ones on the last node do finish with these output:

```
/bin/bash: 0: command not found
/bin/bash: 1: command not found
/bin/bash: 2: command not found
/bin/bash: 3: command not found
/bin/bash: 4: command not found
/bin/bash: 5: command not found
/bin/bash: 6: command not found
```

Obviously, my input is somehow misinterpreted, but I have no idea how, as I'm not an experienced user of GNU Parallel.

My jobscript looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#SBATCH --job-name job-name
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
#SBATCH --array=0-2

[ -z "$PARALLEL_SEQ" ] && { exec parallel --retry-failed --retries 5 --joblog joblog.txt -a numtasks $0 ; }

TASKS_PER_NODE=`cat numtasks | wc -l`

IDX=$(( ${TASKS_PER_NODE} * ${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID} + ${PARALLEL_SEQ} - 1 ))

mkdir "res-${IDX}"
cd "res-${IDX}"
source ${HOME}/.bashrc
conda activate myenv
cp ../myscript.py .

python3 ./myscript.py ${IDX}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear to me what numtasks contain. Is is just a sequence?

I would use a bash function. To me that is much more readable than conditionally `exec $0`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash                                                                       
#SBATCH --job-name job-name                                                               
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1                                                                 
#SBATCH --array=0-2                                                                       

doit() {
    TASKS_PER_NODE=`cat numtasks | wc -l`

    IDX=$(( ${TASKS_PER_NODE} * ${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID} + ${PARALLEL_SEQ} - 1 ))

    mkdir "res-${IDX}"
    cd "res-${IDX}"
    source ${HOME}/.bashrc
    conda activate myenv
    cp ../myscript.py .

    python3 ./myscript.py ${IDX}
}
export -f doit
export SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID

parallel --retry-failed --retries 5 --joblog joblog.txt -a numtasks doit
```

You might also want to check out the options `--memfree`/`--memsuspend`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should edit your jobscript to properly pass the value of `${IDX}` as an argument to your Python script!

something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#SBATCH --job-name job-name
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
#SBATCH --array=0-2

[ -z "$PARALLEL_SEQ" ] && { exec parallel --retry-failed --retries 5 --joblog joblog.txt -a numtasks $0 ; }

TASKS_PER_NODE=$(cat numtasks | wc -l)

IDX=$(( ${TASKS_PER_NODE} * ${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID} + ${PARALLEL_SEQ} - 1 ))

mkdir "res-${IDX}"
cd "res-${IDX}"
source ${HOME}/.bashrc
conda activate myenv
cp ../myscript.py .

python3 ./myscript.py "${IDX}"
```